# What does 'very' mean in this sentence and why do we need it?

Tags: determiners, superlatives

Here is the sentence:

> The brothers, Primo and Secondo, want to serve the **very** best Italian cooking.

My question is what means very in this sentence? Why do we need the determiner **very** in this sentence?

Comment: Look it up [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/very_1?q=very) (Meaning 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'very' here is used only for emphasis.

You don't actually need it to form this sentence, for instance, 'the best Italian cooking' and 'the very best Italian cooking' technically mean the same thing, as 'best' is a superlative.

In English, we use 'very best' just to add extra description for emphasis, even though the meaning technically doesn't change.